# Swfit: Tableview passing values to Prototype Cell and finding which row a control was triggered

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my app I have two table view controllers.

`tableViewController1` has a list of rows with text label and loads some data from Core Data, an important value is a 'deviceid' that I need pretty much for anything in my app.

`tableViewController2` has 1-5 rows depending on which row you selected in tableViewController1.

I've implemented a prototype custom cell that has its own class and implemented a label (label2) and a segment control (segment1).

When I select for example the first row on tableViewController1, I see 3 rows in tableViewController2, thus 3 segment controls.

With a protocol I can trigger back to the tableViewController2 that the segment control has changed value but how do I know which one of the three was triggered?

I tried using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath but if the user taps the segment control only then the row is not selected so it doesn't trigger.

Also if I want to pass the 'deviceid' from the tableViewController2 to the prototype cell, is that possible? I tried again with the protocol but had no luck.

Code for what I'm trying to do:

[EDIT] I took the input and managed to get it working without the need for protocol but adding an action at cell level, is this the 'proper' way to do it though?

```
class TableViewController1: UITableViewController {

    var rowItems = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    var deviceid = "123456789"
    var rowToSend: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowItems.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell1") as! TableViewCell1
        cell.label1.text = rowItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        rowToSend = indexPath.row
        performSegueWithIdentifier("seg1", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "seg1") {

            let theDestination = (segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController2)
            theDestination.deviceid = deviceid
            theDestination.incomingRow = rowToSend
        }
    }

}

class TableViewController2: UITableViewController {
    var deviceid = ""
    var incomingRow: Int = 0

    var parameterItems = ["Parameter 1", "Parameter 2", "Parameter 3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if incomingRow < 2 {
            parameterItems = ["Parameter 1", "Parameter 2", "Parameter 3"]
        } else {
            parameterItems = ["Parameter 1", "Parameter 4", "Parameter 5"]
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parameterItems.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell2") as! TableViewCell2

        cell.label2.text = parameterItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.segment1.addTarget(self, action: "controlChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        return cell
    }

    func controlChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
        let cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
        if let myRow = cellIndexPath?.row {
           println("row: \(myRow) with value: \(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) for deviceid: \(deviceid)")
        }

    }   
}


class TableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var segment1: UISegmentedControl!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code with your existing implementation

Comment: @ZeMoon My mistake, have added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get from a control to the index path of the cell is as follows:

```
func controlChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   let point = sender.convertPoint(CGRectZero toView: self.tableView)
   let indexPath = self.tableView(indexPathForRowAtPoint: point)
   // your logic based on indexPath
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mundi, but where do I add this snippet? I get errors in both the TableViewController2 and TableViewCell2.

Comment: I think from the function name and expressions like `self.tableView`, it is clear where to put that. This is the common handler of the segmented controls.